# How to store a Word document as a BLOB in mySQL with Coldfusion

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, blob

A client wants Word documents saved to a mySQL database despite me arguing against. The documents themselves should not be particularly large, no more than 1 MB each. I have enabled BLOB in CF administrator and set the blob buffer to 1,000,000

Here's my SQL

```
<cfset newMessageID=1569>
<cfset fileName="c:\temp\0.doc">

<cffile action = "readbinary" 
file = "#fileName#"
variable = "fileData">

<cfquery name="addFile" datasource='#application.dsn#'>
    INSERT into files (fileID, fileData)
    Values (#newMessageID#, <cfqueryparam value="#fileData#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_BLOB">)
</cfquery>
```

I get "Data truncation: Data too long for column 'filedata' at row 1" error. The filedata field in the files table is definitely set to blob. What am I doing wrong?

CF 9.01, mySQL 5.4

What am I doing wrong

Comment: Think you need to wrap the `#fileData#` in `ToBase64()` - see docs here: http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_f_08.html Read uses `BinaryEncode()` to convert it back: http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_a-b_31.html#4989676

Comment: I tried that already. If I simply convert toBase64 it throws a cast error with my cfqueryparam. If I run without cfqueryparam I'm back to "data too long for column 'filedata'"

Comment: @Saul - What kind of `blob`? There are different types long, medium, ... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html

Comment: @ Leigh - just this minute found that out. It was blob, changed to longblob and that fixed it. Is my math right in thinking mediumblob will be too small, and only take just over 2^16 = 65 536 bytes?

Comment: @Saul - Yes, but that is `blob`. Medium blob is 2^24 ~ 16777216. If you think you might ever exceed that, then go with `longblob`.

Comment: Thanks Leigh, do you want to put your comment as a post and I can accept.

Comment: Sure. (S.O. hates brevity...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What kind of blob? There are different types including [long and medium blob](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html). Blob is (approximately) 2^16 = 65,536 bytes, medium blob is 2^24 = 16,777,216 bytes. If you think you might exceed medium blob, then go with longblob ie 2^32.

Answer (score -2):

Just a bad, bad idea.

I would either:

1. Convert it to text file 1st, then you simplify the importing of just raw text.
2. Or just upload it to some folder, and make it available for downloading again or viewing online

your cutting your own throat trying to store it in the database...

Comment: You read in the OP that I argued against it right? At the end of the day he who pays the piper ... anyway I don't think it will be too bad. I do parse the Word document and store in a table for the meta data which is all that is used for any queries/joins. The files table just has the ID and mediumblob. On the plus side file security, logging and backup is easier ;-)